# nodejs multer is getting req.file but not uploading it to destination

Tags: node.js, file, express, upload, multer

multer.js

```
var path = require("path"),
multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, next){
        next(null, '../public/imgs/');
        return;
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

module.exports = upload;
```

router.js

```
//handle createPartner route
router.post("/partner/new", upload.single('image'), function(req, res){

  console.log(req.file);
  console.log(req.body);

  req.body.Partner["image"] ="/static/imgs/"+req.file.filename;

  req.body.Partner.body = req.sanitize(req.body.Partner.body);

  Partner.create(req.body.Partner, function(err, createdPartner){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.redirect("/admin/partner/new");
      }else{
          res.redirect("/partners");
      }
  });
});
```

I get the following console.log

```
{ fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'fb.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: '../public/imgs/',
  filename: 'image-1521727739861.png',
  path: '../public/imgs/image-1521727739861.png',
  size: 21532 }
{ Partner: { name: 'test', bio: 'test', image: '', website: 'test' } }
```

so multer does get the file but it doesn't upload it to the destination! The permissions for /public and /public/imgs are 777. Everywhere I searched uses the other method for multer but that way I'll have to specify (single/multiple/any) in advance which isn't right.

Comment: I have had a similar issue in the past and it was to do with my destination path not being correct. To test it out, you can try putting in the full path to your images from folder from your root directory. e.g. if you're on mac `/Users/<computername>/project/public/imgs/`

Comment: Thanks this worked! but it doesn't seem right at all. I mean I'll have to keep updating the path when deploying, why can't it be relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the absolute path as I mentioned in comments.

You can easily do this by utilising `path.join` like follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var dir = path.join(__dirname, '../public/imgs')
```

That will concatenate `__dirname` which is the absolute path of the current file with your images file.

Comment: No problem @KaisSalha. Please mark answer as correct if it helped